# How to restore System Preferences.app without reinstalling?

Tags: system-settings

My younger brother decided to `sudo rm -r /Applications/System\ Preferences.app`. Yeah, it was a pretty stupid thing to do.

(In his defense, it's probably my fault for giving him bad habits--whenever I set up new macs, I always forcibly remove iTunes, Chess, and other preinstalled applications that I consider useless.)

He is currently running MacOS Sierra, and aside from the fact that he can't change any settings, his computer appears to be running fine.

I told my brother to redownload the Sierra installer from the Mac App Store, use [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com) to extract the System Preferences application, and copy it back to his applications folder.

He did so, but the newly-extracted System Preferences app doesn't work. It opens, but displays a blank window with no preference panes to click on. I advised him to do a reinstall, but he doesn't want to.

How can my brother get System Preferences back?

Comment: He needs to reinstall OS X.

Comment: He has a Time Machine backup, right?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the latest combo updater for Sierra is probably the first thing I'd try. Won't overwrite anything it doesn't need to, but should put back anything that's missing.

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1918?locale=en_IE